# Можно ли возвращать исключения-наследники?

Tags: ооп, solid

Можно ли возвращать исключения-наследники? Не нарушает ли это SOLID?

Comment: Какой пункт из SOLID будет нарушен?

Comment: В целом ответ `нужно`, что соответствует букве `I`